# Identity Server 4 : Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, identityserver4

I have set up identity server 4 to extent Umbraco so it uses a custom role provider.

Everything was working but now when I get redirected to my Identity server I get this error:

[image]

Can anybody shine some light on this error? I have tried rolling back my code in source control but nothing I do seems to help it. Is there anywhere I can see an error log?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Well... the best we can say is that the client is unauthorized. Look at the client in the database and ensure it's valid

Comment: Hey, As far as I know the clients are stored in code for Identity Server and I've check the values. can't see any issues as I haven't touched this code in weeks. strange.

Comment: That's only for development... Check the application that hosts the identity server. The logs should tell you more useful information

Comment: I think I found it, I published the site to azure to look at the logs and found the client_id was not correct (kind of), i have it in a config but it was not the value being sent, so I changed it to a new value and it started working. does ID have a txt log file locally? I can;t seem to find any info on it. Thanks!!

Comment: Check error logs written by Identity Server. The log files will have more details on which value is incorrect, e.g. client id, secret, redirect url etc.

Comment: please check this link for the solution to fix this error. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/installing-9-1-xp0-sorry-there-was-an-error-unauthorized-client

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out this was due to the RedirectUris being incorrect.

This error is thrown if there is anything wrong with the client.

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: For me, IdentityModel was appending "/signin-oidc" to my redirect URI.  After I updated the IdentityServer client config to reflect that, it began to work.

Comment: For me, I had to update the table ClientRedirectUris of the Identity Server database.

Answer (score 10):

The cause may be `RedirectUris` of a client do not include the actual redirect uri the client app is sending. This is configured in `Client.cs` method `GetClients`:

```
new Client
{
    ...
    RedirectUris = new[] { "https://..." }, 
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new[] { "https://..." },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new[] { "https://..." },
}
```

The redirect URI must match exactly the address the client is sending, **including the HTTP scheme** (http, https).

This can be found in log the file that lists allowed URIs and the actual URI of a failed authorization request. Identity server is using serilog, in `program.cs` it can be switched on in `Main` method:

```
...

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File("logs\\the-log-file-name.txt")
    .CreateLogger();

BuildWebHost(args).Run();
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried using https instead of http to access my local sitecore admin panel like this

https://site.local/sitecore and it worked remember its only https !